# Unity UWP Build on Windows Store - Languages supported in packages

Tags: unity-game-engine, uwp, localization, windows-store-apps, windows-store

I'm publishing my games on Windows Store, and it supports multiple languages.

But when I upload it to Windows Store, it only shows "English" in the list of supported languages (and on the Windows Store).

[image]

I tried to add manually in "Additional Store listing languages", but this only translate the Store Page, it still shows only English as Supported Language.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/globalizing/use-mat

I also tried every step shown here, but without success... The resulting Visual Studio Project when generating a build from Unity (Il2CPP) does not give the option to add Resources Files (.resw), only Assembly Resource File (.resx)... I renamed the .resx to .resw and I was able to edit it, but the resulting package still only shows English as Supported Language.

I also have a discussion about this on Unity Forum, but still without progress.

https://forum.unity.com/threads/wsa-build-languages-supported-by-your-packages.1176377/#post-7539641

Does anyone have any tips or information on how to resolve this?

Comment: Same problem with unity+UWP. Answer here:[forum.unity](https://forum.unity.com/threads/wsa-build-languages-supported-by-your-packages.1176377/)